# Support for XmlResult & XmlValueProviderFactory in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xml, json

You would notice that JsonResult & JsonValueProviderFactory are both included in Asp.Net MVC.

Why do you think Microsoft has not added XmlResult & XmlValueProviderFactory to MVC?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering the same thing. In WCF, you can do this easily, so why not in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has written one [here](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/xml-to-asp.net-mvc-action-method)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that somebody else has written both XmlResult & XmlValueProviderFactory. But I want to know why Microsoft did not support it along with Json? What is their argument?